# Which video game voice actors have reprised their roles in a live-action film or TV show adaptation?

Tags: acting, voice-acting, video-game-adaptation

I recently [learned](https://www.thewrap.com/the-last-of-us-hbo-marlene-merle-dandridge-interview/) that Merle Dandridge, the actor who voiced Marlene in *[The Last of Us](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_Us)* (2013 video game), has reprised her role in the [2023 live-action TV show adaptation of the game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_of_Us_(TV_series)).

Was this the first and only instance of this happening? Or **have there been other instances of video game voice actors reprising their roles in a later live-action film or TV show based on the video game?**

Note: I'm only looking for instances where the character being portrayed first appeared as a video game character and has since been reprised as a live-action character, not a CGI, animated, voice-only, or other non-live-action performance.

Comment: The character of Augustus Cold from Gears of War was modeled after the voice actor, and I suspect he is/was slated to appear in the movie (but the movie hasn't been released yet). There was also support for the Hitman voice actor to play the character in the movie, but obviously that didn't happen.

Comment: I thought that the voice actress that voiced Diana in the Hitman series also voiced her in the first movie, but turns out I was wrong.

Comment: Sorry - I missed that you knew of Merle Dandridge.

Comment: I did a preliminary search using [IMDb's Collaboration Search](https://www.imdb.com/search/common/). Nobody in the Hitman series reprised their role. There's a few people from The Witcher video games series that had roles in the TV series, but it's unclear if they reprised the same roles.